# label hyperlink Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I try to find out in Graphviz, how to make a label "1" colored and at the same time a hyperlink. Is this possible? Please see the example below.

F

```
 <graphviz>

 digraph vvv
 {
 rankdir=LR
 a2 [href="http://www.apple.com"]
 {
 a0->a1[href="http://www.uk.com"] [label="1"] [color =red];
 a1->a2 
 }

 a2[style=filled,color=yellow]
 a0[style=filled,color=lightgrey]

 </graphviz>
```

Answer (score 39):

Yes it's possible.

I'm assuming you are generating SVG output.

If by *make a label "1" colored* you mean the **font color of the label text**, it's as simple as specifying it in the edge attributes:

```
a0->a1[href="http://www.uk.com", fontcolor=yellow, color=red label="1"];
```

[`fontcolor`](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fontcolor/) refers to the color of the label's text, whereas [`color`](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/color/) is the color of the edge itself.

If you want to have an **edge label with a colored background**, [`fillcolor`](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fillcolor/) is supposed to work. However, it doesn't (may depend on the version of graphviz). Therefore you may use [**HTML-like labels**](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and specify the `BGCOLOR`:

```
 a0->a1[href="http://www.uk.com", fontcolor=red, label=<
     <TABLE CELLBORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
         <TR><TD BGCOLOR="yellow">1KMK</TD></TR>
     </TABLE>
 >, color =red];
```

Comment: It works! Two days and nights work - and an exellent one-hour answer! Great! Thanks a lot! 
F

Comment: I'm glad it helps! Since this is your first question on SO: don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: broken link HTML-like labels

Comment: @JasonS I fixed the links to the documentation, thanks.